# in an empty dictionary, get method, results.get(c, 0) + 1 and results.get(c, 0) confuse me?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
word = input ('Enter a word: ')
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
results = {}

for c in word:
    if c in vowels:
        results[c] = results.get(c, 0)
        # results[c] = results.get(c, 0) + 1
for k, v in results.items():
    print (k, " is present", v, "times")
```

In the above code, I don't understand. what is the mean by -

```
results.get(c, 0) + 1
```

and what is the difference between?

```
results.get(c, 0) + 1 

results.get(c, 0)
```

at first, I thought that "results.get(c, 0) + 1" gives the output based on an empty dictionary, but when I executed this code "results.get(c, 0)", my understanding of get method got confused.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your confusion. The different between `<expr>` and `<expr> + 1` is that the second is the first plus 1.

Comment: my confusion is what does mean by this "results.get(c, 0) + 1"?

Comment: It gets the value of the dictionary entry with key `c`. If that key doesn't exit, it defaults to `0`. Then it adds `1` to that value. Finally, it stores that back into the dictionary element.

Comment: So it adds 1 to `result[c]`, setting it to 1 the first time.

Comment: Maybe you need to reread the documentation of `dict.get()` again to understand how the two arguments work.

Comment: "but when I executed this code "results.get(c, 0)", my understanding of get method got confused." When you were confused by what happened, what was in `results` beforehand? What did you think the answer should be when you use that code on such a `results` input? What answer did you get instead, and how is that different?

Answer (score 0):

```
results.get(c, 0)
```

returns the value of the key `c` in `results`. If the key doesn't exist, it returns `0`.

```
results.get(c, 0) + 1
```

returns the value of the key `c` in `results`  and adds `1` to it. If the key doesn't exist, the value defaults to `0`, it adds `1` to that, so the returned value of the entire expression is `1`.

When you put it in the assignment

```
results[c] = results.get(c, 0) + 1
```

it adds 1 to `results[c]`, but if the key doesn't already exist it sets it to `1`.

So the code counts how many times each vowel appears in the string. The first time a particular vowel is encountered, it sets `results[c]` to 1, the following times it keeps adding 1 to it.